# How can I programmatically compose a message on Watch?

Tags: swift, watchkit

How can I open the Messages app to the compose screen, with the message body preloaded with specific text?

Comment: @RMenke I checked if MessageUI was available for watchOS (it isn't), and looked for any frameworks that might be the equivalent, but came up empty.

Comment: whereEver you are triggering this from, can you invoke opening of this url: sms:123-456-8900, but I don't think you can populate a message!https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/SMSLinks/SMSLinks.html

Comment: @Jatin 1) I do not believe you can open links on Apple Watch (UIApplication does not seem to be available). 2) I know it's possible to populate the message, baca use I have seen it done.

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7370937?start=0&tstart=0, it crashes accordign to this user, lets dig some documentation.....how else are you populating then, there has to be a urlscheme or some new API's unknown to us

Comment: i was right found it: https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKExtension_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKExtension/openSystemURL:

Comment: this is how you open messages app:

func openSystemURL(_ url: NSURL)

your NSURL will be sms:234234342

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **@Jatin** for finding the `openSystemURL(url: NSURL)` function.

Here's the code:

```
let messageBody = "Hello World!"
let urlSafeBody = messageBody.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!
WKExtension.sharedExtension().openSystemURL(NSURL(string: "sms:&body=\(urlSafeBody)")!)
```

Comment: I'm sure it is something dumb, but I am not getting this code to work. When I execute it, it shows this error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. 

How is urlSafeBody nil?!

Comment: It's not `urlSafeBody` that is nil. You're force-unwrapping `NSURL` which happens to be nil because its URL string is malformed.  See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36567031/4151918) for details.

Comment: can i send mail?

Comment: Swift 5.0

let urlSafeBody =  msgBody.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
        if let urlSafeBody = urlSafeBody, let url = NSURL(string: "sms:&body=\(urlSafeBody)") {
            WKExtension.shared().openSystemURL(url as URL)
             }

Answer (score 7):

[Benjy's answer is almost correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34459852/4151918), but has one issue.

Since `urlSafeBody` isn't unwrapped, string interpolation yields

> sms:&body=Optional("Hello%20World!")

which is causing `NSURL` initialization to return nil, since the URL string is malformed.

Here's a working example which conditionally unwraps optionals.  This removes any possibility of crashes related to nil optionals being force-unwrapped.

```
let messageBody = "Hello World!"
let urlSafeBody = messageBody.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())
if let urlSafeBody = urlSafeBody, url = NSURL(string: "sms:&body=\(urlSafeBody)") {
    WKExtension.sharedExtension().openSystemURL(url)
}
```

Comment: Can I send mail?