# WatchKit SMS with preset body

Tags: swift, sms, watchkit, nsurl, option-type

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361531/how-can-i-programmatically-compose-a-message) which should have helped me, but the solution there is not working for me, and I am not sure if something has changed or if the problem is with my code.

```
let messageBody = "hello"
let urlSafeBody = messageBody.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())
print("URLSAFEBODY: \(urlSafeBody)")
WKExtension.sharedExtension().openSystemURL(NSURL(string: "sms:&body=\(urlSafeBody)")!)
```

When this code is executed, I get the message that optional `urlSafeBody` was force unwrapped while nil, leading to a crash. Why is `urlSafeBody` nil? I know that I'm force unwrapping it, but I don't understand why it is ever nil after being assigned explicitly.

Comment: This is a valid question, no need to down vote ..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not `urlSafeBody` that is nil.  As you can see from your print statement, it contains an optional string:

> URLSAFEBODY: Optional("hello")

That will actually turn out to be a problem for the chain in the next statement, since you haven't unwrapped that string before it is interpolated.

If you examined your `NSURL` string URL, you'd see it contained:

> sms:&body=Optional("hello")

This is going to cause `NSURL` initialization to fail, because its string URL is malformed.  The fatal error then happens because you force-unwrapped the nil result from `NSURL(string:)`

**How to resolve this:**

You want to conditionally unwrap any strings which might be nil. You can do this via `if let` or `guard let` optional binding:

```
let messageBody = "hello"
let urlSafeBody = messageBody.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())
if let urlSafeBody = urlSafeBody, url = NSURL(string: "sms:&body=\(urlSafeBody)") {
    WKExtension.sharedExtension().openSystemURL(url)
}
```

Notice that the `urlSafeBody` was unwrapped before it was used in the string interpolation, and `url` was also unwrapped after initialization.

Since it's certain that the url is not nil, it can be safely passed to `openSystemURL`.

You should always strive to avoid force-unwrapping variables which may be nil, as that will certainly lead to a crash.